# meteor blaze rendered being called before DOM completion

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template that shows a QRCode with the user id  :

```
        <template name="pairDevice">
          {{#with currentUser}}
          <div id="qrcode"></div>
          <div class="key" id="qrcodeValue" style="display: none;">{{id}}</div>
          {{/with}}
        </template>
```

I tried setting the value from the rendered and from the helper, but it's always the same problem `$('#qrcode')` and `$('#qrcodeValue')` return `[]` as the fields don't exist yet.

```
Template.pairDevice.rendered = function(){
  if (!location.origin) {
     location.origin = location.protocol+"//"+location.host;
  }
 // $('#qrcode').qrcode({width  : 128, height :128 ,text : $('#qrcodeValue').html()});
};

Template.pairDevice.helpers({
  'id' : function(){
    var appUser =Meteor.user();
    var value = location.origin  + ";" + appUser._id + ";" + appUser.emails[0].address;
     $('#qrcode').qrcode({width  : 128, height :128 ,text : value});
    return value;
  }
});
```

I know that Blaze renders only once, but how can i get it to render after the DOM completion?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you move the `{{#with currentUser}}` outside of the template? (So remove it from `pairDevice`, then call pairDevice with `{{#with currentUser}}{{> pairDevice}}{{/with}}`)

Comment: It works! any idea why ?

Comment: When you first refresh the page, I believe `currentUser` is undefined for a short time while the client authenticates with its resume token. So when `pairDevice` is first rendered, `currentUser` is undefined so the two divs `#qrcode` and `#qrcodeValue` are not rendered initially. By moving the `with` outside of the template, the `pairDevice` template is not rendered at all until `currentUser` is defined.

Comment: Since this worked, I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `{{#with currentUser}}` outside of the template.

```html
<template name="pairDevice">
  <div id="qrcode"></div>
  <div class="key" id="qrcodeValue" style="display: none;">{{id}}</div>
</template>

<!-- call it like this -->
{{#with currentUser}}
  {{> pairDevice}}
{{/with}}
```

When you first refresh the page, I believe `currentUser` is undefined for a short time while the client authenticates with its resume token. So when `pairDevice` is first rendered, `currentUser` is undefined so the two divs `#qrcode` and `#qrcodeValue` are not there when the `rendered` callback is called. By moving the with outside of the template, the `pairDevice` template is not rendered at all until `currentUser` is defined.